# Java and mysql database, updating values always delayed

Tags: java, mysql, database

hello i'm a student who's working about java program

I've been using 2 Jframe and currently working on database

I've encountered this problem where Whenever I update the value of the database from Jframe1 and I jumped to Jframe2 where the database is connected to see if it also Updated on the Jframe2 but turns out It's still back in it's old value

and I've also had this summary of the problem based on my observation

let's assume the value of it at first attempt is January and in my first attempt I updated it into February then I've jumped to Jframe2 but it's still January 
in second attempt I tried to change the value to March and after jumping to Jframe2 the value is now February

I've come to a conclusion that the Update function of my program and showing it is delayed I don't know what I did wrong, by the way this is just me practicing java and databases

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE identifier SET MONTH = ? WHERE ID = '1'");
    if(month.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("January")){
        Jan a = new Jan();
        ps.setString(1,"January");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        a.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
```

this is the sample of updating of it if the update event is called

```
public void getMonth()
{ try{
    ResultSet TEMP;
        Connection con = getConnection();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM identifier where id='1'";
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {

            String value =rs.getString("MONTH");
            title.setText(value);
        }

}
catch(Exception e){
```

and this is the sample of getting the value from the database in Jframe2

Comment: Have you checked the database after the update to validate the values?

Comment: yes and I'm keeping an eye on it, when I update values in Jframe1 it changes the database but after jumping to Jframe2 It's always delayed I'm currently observing it and it's the same loop 1st attempt of change 1-2 but turns out to be still 1 but on 2nd attempt of change 2-3 it's changed but delayed and has the value of 1st attempt which is 2

Comment: Are you checking the database directly or checking the results on your application?

Comment: I'm doing both, I have my database open and i'm comparing the updates if they're updating or not, the database value changes when i update on Jframe1 but the Jframe2 can't seem to keep up

Comment: There is no delay is updating the database, rather, the application context has not been refreshed.

Comment: it's okay sir I've already resolved the issue, I just added an event in mouse motion whenever you moved the mouse it'll refresh the application context. thanks sir

Comment: 'whenever you moved the mouse it'll refresh the application context' - this would work but ... it is a very expensive operation - Perhaps consider another event?